# Hi. I’d Like To Identify The Bricks In The Picture

Tags: part-identification, piece-information, bricks-and-pieces

[image: ![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcwfG.jpg)]

I’d like to buy these bricks but I’m having trouble identifying some of them.

Comment: I count 28 different (okay, a few only differs in colour) pieces, some of which are very ordinary. I don't think anyone is going to spend all the time it will take to write an answer identifying everything in that picture. So, please focus on the parts you're actually having trouble with.

Comment: I'd be more helpful if you could also mention the source of the pic, which seems to be an existing set or MOC :)

Answer (score 9):

- 001 - [Minifigure, Utensil Coin.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=Minifigure,%20Utensil%20Coin%20#T=A) or [Minifigure, Utensil Ring 1 x 1 - Lord of the Rings.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=110116#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) Alternative answer by *Alexander "Hawk-eyes" O'Mara*, Thanks.
- 002 - [Plate, Round 1 x 1 with Open Stud.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=85861&name=Plate,%20Round%201%20x%201%20with%20Open%20Stud&category=%5BPlate,%20Round%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- 003 - [Bar 1L with 1 x 1 Round Plate with Hollow Stud Black.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32828&name=Bar%201L%20with%201%20x%201%20Round%20Plate%20with%20Hollow%20Stud&category=%5BBar%5D#T=S&C=86&O=%7B%22color%22:%2286%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- 004 - [Bar 1L with 1 x 1 Round Plate with Hollow Stud Light Bluish Gray.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32828&name=Bar%201L%20with%201%20x%201%20Round%20Plate%20with%20Hollow%20Stud&category=%5BBar%5D#T=S&C=86&O=%7B%22color%22:%2286%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- 005 - [Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with 1 Stud with Groove (Jumper).](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=104287#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- 006 - [Minifigure, Utensil Tool Box Wrench - 3-Rib Handle.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11402i&name=Minifigure,%20Utensil%20Tool%20Box%20Wrench%20-%203-Rib%20Handle&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Utensil%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- 007 - [Slope, Curved 2 x 1 No Studs.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=119122#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- 008 - [Bracket 1 x 2 - 2 x 2 Inverted.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=99207&name=Bracket%201%20x%202%20-%202%20x%202%20Inverted&category=%5BBracket%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- 009 - [Plate, Modified 1 x 1 Rounded with Handle.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=146781#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- 010 - [Plate, Modified 1 x 2 Rounded with 2 Open Studs.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=35480&name=Plate,%20Modified%201%20x%202%20Rounded%20with%202%20Open%20Studs&category=%5BPlate,%20Modified%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- 011 - [Plate 1 x 2.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=378#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- 012 - [Plate 2 x 3.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3021&name=Plate%202%20x%203&category=%5BPlate%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- 013 - [Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Handle on Side - Free Ends.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2540&name=Plate,%20Modified%201%20x%202%20with%20Handle%20on%20Side%20-%20Free%20Ends&category=%5BPlate,%20Modified%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- 014 - [Plate, Modified 1 x 4 Offset.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4590&name=Plate,%20Modified%201%20x%204%20Offset&category=%5BPlate,%20Modified%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- 015 - [Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Pin Hole on Top.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11458&name=Plate,%20Modified%201%20x%202%20with%20Pin%20Hole%20on%20Top&category=%5BPlate,%20Modified%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- 016 - [Slope 30 1 x 1 x 2/3 Clear Transparent.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=54200&name=Slope%2030%201%20x%201%20x%202/3&category=%5BSlope%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- 017 - [Plate, Modified 1 x 1 with Clip Vertical.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4085&name=Plate,%20Modified%201%20x%201%20with%20Clip%20Vertical%20-%20Undetermined%20Type&category=%5BPlate,%20Modified%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- 018 - [Bracket 1 x 2 - 1 x 2.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=109981#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- 019 - [Slope 30 1 x 1 x 2/3 Blue.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=54200&name=Slope%2030%201%20x%201%20x%202/3&category=%5BSlope%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- 020 - [Tile 1 x 1 with Groove.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3070b&name=Tile%201%20x%201%20with%20Groove%20(3070)&category=%5BTile%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- 021 - [Brick, Modified 1 x 1 with Stud on 1 Side.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=87087&name=Brick,%20Modified%201%20x%201%20with%20Stud%20on%201%20Side&category=%5BBrick,%20Modified%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- 022 - [Slope, Curved 2 x 2 No Studs.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15068&name=Slope,%20Curved%202%20x%202%20No%20Studs&category=%5BSlope,%20Curved%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- 023 - [Technic, Pin 1/2.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4274&name=Technic,%20Pin%201/2&category=%5BTechnic,%20Pin%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- 024 - [Brick, Round 1 x 1 Open Stud.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3062b&name=Brick,%20Round%201%20x%201%20Open%20Stud&category=%5BBrick,%20Round%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- 025 - [Brick 1 x 1.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3005&name=Brick%201%20x%201&category=%5BBrick%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- 26a - [Tile, Modified 1 x 1 with Clip Blue.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2555&name=Tile,%20Modified%201%20x%201%20with%20Clip&category=%5BTile,%20Modified%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- 26b - [Tile, Modified 1 x 1 with Clip Red.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2555&name=Tile,%20Modified%201%20x%201%20with%20Clip&category=%5BTile,%20Modified%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- 26c - [Tile, Modified 1 x 1 with Clip Black.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2555&name=Tile,%20Modified%201%20x%201%20with%20Clip&category=%5BTile,%20Modified%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

Comment: Wow, I'm surprised anyone was willing to do all that. I'm not sure, but I think the first one might be a LOTR ring. +1 either way though.

Comment: A+ for the effort!